# Hausdorff space which is not Urysohn space.

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ and for every $p\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, $p$ has the usual neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. Basic neighborhoods of $0$ is the sets of the form $\{[0, \frac{1}{n}):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ while basic neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the sets of the form $\{(-\frac{1}{n}, 0)\cup\{\infty\}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
I think $X$, endowed with this topology, is a Hausdorff space.

Can We say that  for every closed neighborhood $N$ of diagonal $X$,  $\Delta_X$ , in $X\times X$,  $(0, \infty)\in N$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @SolubleFish, Ok, thanks for it.

Comment: why the uniform spaces tag?

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $\overline{U} \cap \overline{V} \neq \emptyset$ whenever $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $0$ and $V$ one for $\infty$. This implies the property you ask about. The above first fact is already a direct proof that $X$ is not Urysohn.